# AngularJS - Component receiving dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, components

Morning,

I've got an issue with a new component that I have written, where a value is not being passed to the controller how I would imagine that it would.

So let's take this component declaration, you can see that i'm passing in two strings, and an object, that object equates to a number from a parent controller. Let's assume that both 'url' and 'pagesize' work nicely already  -which they do :)

```
<paging url="/myurl.html" pagesize="10" numberofitems="ctrl.mynumber"></paging>
```

You can see that I have created a new module here, which at the moment only displays a paragraph tag with the number 'ctrl.numberofitems' variable shown within it. It is important to know that this works and the value displays correctly.

```
    angular.module('PagingModule', [])
    .component('paging', {
        scope: {},
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindings: {
            url: '@',
            pagesize: '@',
            numberofitems: '='
        },
        controller: pagingController,
        template: '<p>{{ctrl.numberofitems}}</p>'
    });

    function pagingController() {
        var vm = this;
        $scope.$watch("ctrl.numberofitems", function (val) { //ADDED THE WATCH AND CAN NOW SEE THE VALUE UNDEFINED, THEN POPULATED CORRECTLY
            console.log(val);
        });
    }
```

When I try to refer to 'vm.numberofitems' do I receive undefined? 'pagesize' and 'url' are both perfectly accessible and populated at this point.

EDIT: now, if i refer to the $scope.watch as shown above, i can access the value that has be pushed in from my controller - what i do note now though is that the value is UNDEFINED, then when the promise from the service is resolved, it changes to the actual list itself.

The question now changes :) why do i have to do this $watch? it seems complete overkill and is obviously expensive; am i just missing a really obvious pattern that i can use?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting for `$onInit`.

> After the controller is instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings will be bound to the controller properties. You can access these bindings once they have been initialized by providing a controller method called `$onInit`, which is called after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized.

-- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-

---

The next thing to do is put a `$watch` on it.

```
$scope.$watch("ctrl.numberofitems", function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

If the view can see it, the watch should see it.

Comment: still nothing, what is the best way to go about debugging this? clearly the item is being passed as it appears in the view, just not defined in the controller..... FYI i've added the $onInit to the code above.